# I can edit a post even if another edit is pending (waiting for review) - is this a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits

Recently I noticed, that there is a way to edit a question even if another edit is pending and still waiting to be reviewed. Is this a bug or intended?

As an example:

I have a question like this:

[image: Question]

And now I want to edit it, but there is already an edit pending:

[image: Edit pending]

With the 'normal' way to click on the edit button I can't edit it, other than review it.

But now I found out if you change the URL from:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/28011705/how-can-i-get-an-if-into-mysql-code
```

to this:

```
stackoverflow.com/posts/28011705/edit
                //^^^^^ Changed  ^^^^
```

I'm getting into the edit of the question without reviewing the pending edit! In addition to that, the pending edit is in the edit I'm in with the URL included plus the edit summary is already filled in with the edit summary of the pending edit.

[image: Edit summary]

Now I can improve the edit more OR just leave it and post this edit.

Now this alone doesn't let me 100% think that this is a bug. But I also found out that this doesn't work for Tag edit's. Now I think this is a bug and should be the same like with the Tag edit's?

Because if you press the button `Propose Tag Wiki`, the URL change to this:

```
stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/109478
```

Now you can go though every tag with de/increasing the value at the end of the URL. But if you hit a tag which has a pending edit you can't 'overwrite' the pending edit like with a question shown above. Instead you get a `Page Not Found` like this:

[image: Page not found]

The 'trick' with editing a question that way works also for answers, but there you just have to get the ID by clicking on share and then you see the first number is the ID and you can change the URL the same way as I have shown it with the question.

Is this a bug or intended? Should it be like with the tag edits, that you get a "Page Not Found"?

Comment: I _think_ the edit page you get is the equivalent of hitting "improve edit" on the review, once you submit the edit. If that's the case, I wouldn't really call it _a bug_, just a different UI to do the same thing.

Comment: @KevinBrown That could it be and for the tag wiki it doesn't works for me because i don't have 20'000 rep, have to look into that

Comment: I'd like to see how this is [tag:status-bydesign], this has not been explained..

Comment: @Shog9 I know you've marked this as [meta-tag:status-bydesign] but I'd like to add that this bypasses the 20 post limit on the suggested edit queue FYI.  If I click on `edit(1)` when there is a suggested edit pending, it tells me what the pending edit is, but will not let me do anything because I have already hit my limit, but if I use the URL trick in the Q, it bypasses that and goes straight to editor.

Comment: @Chrismas007 But you don't get 'review points' for suggested edits, it's just a "normal edit" from you, or do you get points?

Comment: @Rizier123  Good question, I will try to test when I find a post with a suggested edit.

Comment: @Rizier123 I was able to test and by using your workaround, it loads the suggested edit into my page.  If I "save" the suggested edit, that would normally approve the edit, give 2 points credit to the editor, then show my modified edit.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27421311/revisions THREW OUT the suggested edit and only took my edit.  Def bug there.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I know that you like 'overwrites' the pending edit, but you got 2 points for that? If yes then i'm 200% sure this is a bug.

Comment: @Rizier123 I did not get any points.  But NORMALLY, the person who's suggested edit I was messing with, WOULD get 2 points.  It appears their edit was thrown out.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247321/workaround-for-seeing-suggested-edits-after-20-review-limit

Comment: @Chrismas007 You're right! It's slightly different from the improve button! After the first comment i really thought it's the same as the improve button, but if you use the improve button the pending edit get's +2, but with this 'workaround' no one get's points plus you can use the suggested edit and overwrite it

Comment: @Chrismas007 This question also shows this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251 If you take a look at the accepted answer under: `What does the "Improve" button do?` There it says that the original editor would get +2 if it was helpful, but with this trick you overwrite it and the OE doesn't gets any points

Comment: See my answer, @Chrismas007.

Comment: You can't do that anymore! It redirects you to a page where with: `There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. You have full editing privileges - therefore, your edits *always* take priority over edits suggested by less-privileged users. You're the 1%, chowing down on textual caviar while the masses gnaw at moldy crusts of bread.

Anyway, the primary reason this behavior exists is to handle cases where multiple people *start* editing and a suggested edit is submitted (but not approved!) before the privileged edit is submitted. We can't keep the suggested edit around anymore - the revision it's based on is no longer valid, and there's a good chance approving it would inadvertently roll back other changes. So we silently reject it... This rejection is *similar* to the "Reject and Edit" option available from review, but differs in two key areas:

1. The rejection *reason* is different. Instead of going on about "critical issues", it merely states, "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."
2. The rejection doesn't count against the editor; you can't get edit-banned due to edit conflicts.

Note that you don't have sufficient privileges to submit edits to tag wikis without approval, so you don't fall into the "privileged user" category there.

Comment: Hm. But it wasn't about the pending edit getting rejected when the direct edit is submitted, but getting to the edit interface even though there's a pending edit. Was it?

Comment: Same thing, @Deduplicator. I'll wager most of these edits come in because the editor *doesn't know* that a suggested edit has been submitted, not because folks are intentionally modifying URLs - after all, most privileged users aren't going to actually see a separate edit page anyway.

Comment: So if this [tag:status-bydesign], and we have superior editing privileges, why can't we override a pending edit by just editing the question itself? Why do we need to use this strange hack? Most of the USA users don't know this probably, but this place is dead during your night time and sometimes some new user tries to edit some question and that edit getting stacked in the reviewing queue for hours (especially if there are disagreement if whenever approve or reject it) and you can't do anything about it (unless you happened to see this meta by chance)

Comment: You can, @david - there are two edit buttons in review for exactly this.

Comment: @Shog9 But there are not two edit buttons on the actual page.  I'm not using the review queue at the moment, but I want to make an edit.  It would be great if the second button could be there as well.

Comment: The other problem I have is that I see that someone has made the same edit I was going to make, and I approve their edit.  Then it waits for other approvals, and then I'm totally stuck.  I always forget that I need to click on improve, add a huge dummy paragraph and submit it, then edit it again and remove the dummy paragraph.  This system is BROKEN.

Comment: @ErickRobertson you don't need to use review queue for that. Just on the post itself click `edit (1)` and you will be given interface to approve/reject/improve that particular edit.

Comment: @Marki555 Still the same problem if I approve it.  If I could un-approve it and then improve it I could work around this BROKEN SYSTEM.

Comment: @ErickRobertson "Reject and Edit" button doesn't do what you want? It will reject the pending edit and allow you to modify the original revision in one step.

Comment: @Marki555 That is unhelpful once I have already approved the edit.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possibly separate bugs in your question:

1. Even if there is a pending edit, if your edits don't have to be reviewed, you can load the standard edit-page, instead of being redirected to the review page.

   That's probably a sin of omission, it should bring you to the review page as a matter of consistency.
2. If there is a pending edit, and your edit must be reviewed (which, as you are between 2000 and 20000, means only for tag-wikis), you get an incoherent error-page if you try to load the edit-page by manually entering the URL.

   That looks like a bona-fide bug too. It's probably also there for normal posts, but you won't trigger it.

Comment: Generally, unhelpful errors are par for the course when hitting URLs you can't actually get to via the UI. It's probably possible to hit this in some cases without manually composing the URL, but I doubt it is common.

Comment: It's rather simple to hit if the stream-socket is blocked... without going to the trouble of manually crafting an URL.