# Can't Edit Ques/Answer With a Pending Edit When Reviews Maxed Out

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits

I was attempting to edit a question with a pending edit to remove a tag but was presented with the following message:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 5 hours to continue reviewing.

While it is accurate I have hit my review limit for the day I don't want to review the pending edit, I would like to edit the question beyond what was already edited. Obviously I didn't find the question in the review queue. I know this is a fringe case but it seems like a bug. Thoughts?

Comment: I fail to see how it's a bug.  You're trying to review an edit when you've already hit the max.  That you didn't come from the queue doesn't change that.

Comment: Is running into a pending edit supposed to prevent further edits until it's resolved?  If so then you're right @Servy and it's not a bug.

Comment: @Servy I'm not looking to improve upon the pending edits. I had edits of my own that I felt would benefit the post. My edits were completely independent of the pending edits, hence I'm not reviewing the pending edit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, it is.  A 2k+ user can improve the suggested edit (while either approving or rejecting it), but that's considered a review action.

Comment: @Dan And yet the edit needs to be reviewed before other edits can be applied.  You could have reviewed it yourself if you hadn't hit the max, since you have, you'll have to wait for the suggestion to be resolved without you before you can make your edit.  That's the way suggested edits were designed.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the clarification.  That piece of information is probably answer-worthy.

Comment: Same problem on Meta.SE: [Helpless after exhausting daily limit for reviewing suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171129) See also: [I can edit a post even if another edit is pending waiting for review -- is this a bug?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283974)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The edit needs to be reviewed by *someone* (or some group of someones) before other edits can be applied.  By saying that you want to edit the question after the proposed edit is applied is effectively saying that you want to approve the suggested edit (and then edit the post), which is a review action.  You could have reviewed it yourself if you hadn't hit the max, since you have, you'll have to wait for the suggestion to be resolved without you (or until the next calendar day) before you can make your edit. That's the way suggested edits were designed.

Comment: thank you for the explanation of the edit system

Comment: Idea: Allow a few extra reviews per day, just for making edits like this.

Comment: @JonasCz Or just do your reviewing at the end of the day, rather than the start.

Comment: Before I hit 2K, I made quite a few edits on posts only to discover that they have been overridden by an edit made by a 2K+ user a couple seconds later. Were these review actions?

Comment: @arc could have been either.  You'd need to check the review.