# Is there a bypass to "Pending edit review maxed for the day"?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, feature-request-process

I am asking about the "Editing topic & waiting for a review approval" limitations for users that have under 2,000 reputation. I am aware that this question is similar to *[Can't Edit Ques/Answer With a Pending Edit When Reviews Maxed Out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293672/cant-edit-ques-answer-with-a-pending-edit-when-reviews-maxed-out)*.

But, my question/suggestion is "is there a way to bypass/make an exception to this"?

Let's say we have someone who has 100-500 approved edits with 0-5 rejected edits (mostly by community-bot conflicts), shouldn't that user technically be qualified to edit as they have a very high approval rating? Is there a way to manually apply for such?

Comment: The bypass is to get 2,000 reputation, at which point they no longer need to be reviewed.

Comment: At the point someone has 500 approved edits, they're getting close to 2,000 rep.  Either way, that's how the system works.  Since you tagged this as [tag:feature-request], people are going to downvote if they disagree with you.  And I very much disagree with this request.

Comment: @fbueckert Actually, not really. You max out your rep earnings from edit suggestions at 1K... so you can't get to 2k rep by edits alone.

Comment: @Catija Er, you can't?  Since when?  I thought approved edits give +2 rep, until you you have the privilege itself.

Comment: @fbueckert Nope. Max you can earn is 1K... though, unless someone doesn't contribute to the site in any other way, it's extremely uncommon for them to hit that max.

Comment: @Catija That is kinda what I was getting at; if you're suggesting edits, chances are good you're also contributing in other ways, so hitting that point kind of makes it moot.

Comment: That is exactly the point I was trying to make, shouldn't there be an exception to editors that are focusing more on moderation rather than posting answers to questions. Especially if they have a massive amount of approved edits!

Comment: Well, @fbueckert not for me. ;) But, yes... but still, the max exists. The most rep I'll ever have on SO is probably going to be 1101.

Comment: @KhalilGhanem I suggest taking a breath before posting comments like your first one. You have no way of knowing why someone downvoted, and animosity like that does not make for a good basis for discussion. Also, downvotes on meta don't affect your reputation.

Comment: @Catija , that demotivates editors, shouldn't we be motivating people to actually help with the editing of posts? At that point you will just look at a horribly written question with lots of unwrapped code and just move along.. or even answer without cleaning the OP.

Answer (score 2):

So... right now you have a total of 25 suggested edits.

- 4 are rejected
- 21 are accepted

That's not bad... and looking at the four rejected ones, they probably shouldn't have been "rejected", as at least two of three of them were edit conflicts that were valid suggestions and the fourth was rejected and edited but should have been improved instead of rejected.

You've got 114 total reputation, meaning you've earned 36 from edits and the remainder (77) from questions and answers.

That means you earn 32% of your reputation from edits and 68% from posts.

If you continue at that rate, you'll get to the 2K reputation for unlimited editing well before you hit the 1k reputation cap for rep earned from suggested edits (which, if you do the math, takes 500 accepted edits)... this, of course, assumes you don't start downvoting answers once you earn that privilege or give the rep away in bounties. You'll also get a free bonus of 100 reputation once you hit 200 rep.

---

So, in the general case... 500 edits... that's a lot. I'm sure that someone who uses SEDE could find out how many users have ever suggested 500+ edits before reaching 2k reputation... and I'm going to bet it's extremely rare... and, on top of that, you're forgetting one thing...

**Suggested edits are the *only* way to earn reputation from editing**, so, if you really want to earn reputation and get access to the other [moderation abilities](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) such as downvotes, review queues and vote counts... you **need** that reputation in order to actually get there. By giving high-performing editors early access to unlimited editing, we would take away their easiest source of reputation income, which is a reward in itself.

As such, and as someone who only earns reputation on this site from editing and has a 100% edit approval count (out of 10)... no. I don't want this to be implemented.

Comment: Also note that if you reach 1000 rep *before* having 500 accepted edit suggestions, you can no longer earn rep from suggested edits. It's not "max 1000 rep from edits" its "max 1000 rep *to earn +2 per edit.*"

Comment: @Draco18s the [FAQ says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/284336): *The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000.* and my personal experience agrees with that statement... don't forget, you still earn +2 rep for tag wiki edit suggestions until you earn that privilege... the rep limit is total earned, not current rep.

Comment: Huh, I guess my memory must be faulty on that, then.

Comment: Actually, 4 out of 22 rejected means almost 20% bad edits. It's not really good, especially considering many bad edits get approved on Stack Overflow (that is a fact I found the hard way after reviewing thousands of suggested edits, finding more and more edits I rejected being approved anyway, which made me quit reviewing altogether on SO).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't say it was good. :)

Comment: "not bad" implies "good", for me at least. Nothing horrible, but I'd try to explain to the OP it better be improved.