# Prevented from editing when there is a pending edit, but I can still access editor from link in comment

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I've noticed this behavior, which seems inconsistent.  And I don't think it's covered by the [blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) or [associated meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) explaining suggested edits.

When a post has a suggested edit pending, the edit link no longer invokes the editor - it instead presents a window to vote on the suitability of the pending edit.

[image]

By most appearances, **further editing is delayed** until the suggested edit receives sufficient votes.

However, if I *leave any comment* on that post that contains the text `[edit]`, that text will be converted to a link that **will invoke the editor**, and appears to allow me to approve the pending edit with my one *pseudo-vote*.

It smells like an oversight to me, and one of the two behaviors should be brought more in line with the other.

Comment: I know stackoverflow.com has custom rules for suggested edits - so I'm posting to this meta site until it's determined that this affects all of stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe this is doing an "Improve Edit" behind the scenes (which auto approves the suggestion)?  Did you check the revision history?

Comment: Theres a trick that if you go `posts/id/edit` you can access the editor. Community would reject the suggested edit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I did not check.  I already felt a little gross monkeying around with people's posts and the site that's trying to maintain them.  Perhaps someone could make a suggested edit to *this* post if they wanted to learn more.

Comment: You are not approving the edit with a pseudo-vote. You are inadvertently *vetoing* the suggested edit, by submitting a competing edit. The Community User automatically rejects the edit (without penalty) in that case. That said, when loading comments the `edit` link should not be replaced with a working version like that.

Comment: About the "trick" which @Braiam mentioned, see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283974/3933332